# Use of や as "when"

Tags: grammar, particles

In the fourth volume of 白銀のソードブレイカー I found an use of や that I think means "when", similar to と, but I can't find this meaning in my grammars or on the Internet; here's an example:

> ヴァリエガータの部屋にたどりつく**や**、叩き壊さんばかりの勢いで襖を開けた

As I said, I think this や means "when", similar to:

> ヴァリエガータの部屋にたどりつく**と**、叩き壊さんばかりの勢いで襖を開けた

Am I right? If so, what differences are implied in using や instead of と?

Comment: This や is in most of the standard J-E dictionary entries it seems. https://jisho.org/word/%E3%82%84

Comment: I somehow missed that, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is shorten expression of 「ヴァリエガータの部屋にたどりつくやいなや（…や否や）」 this means "just sametime". Please see following for reference https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/17260/meaning/m0u/ 「たどりつくと」does not contain meaning of sametime.